# Why does converting a select element to an array return an array of children elements?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I found something interesting when I accidentally used `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll` while selecting some elements from the page. I normally convert static node lists to an array directly after the query. But since `querySelector` just returns the first matching node it finds, and not a `NodeList`, my script attempted to convert the `select` node to an array. Instead of returning an empty array, it returned the children of the select element.

**Why does converting a `select` element to an array return the children nodes?** This does not work for other elements like `div`:

```js
var selectParent = document.querySelector('.selectParent');
var selectArray = Array.from(selectParent);
console.log(selectArray);

var divParent = document.querySelector('.divParent');
var divArray = Array.from(divParent);
console.log(divArray);
```

```html
<select class="selectParent">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
</select>

<div class="divParent">
  <div>Div 1</div>
  <div>Div 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's mostly a historic compatibiilty thing. [`HTMLSelectElement`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#htmlselectelement) has the two key things it needs to be *array-like*:

- A `length`
- Index-style access

...and those two things relate to its options: `length` is the number of `option` elements in the box, and `[0]`, `[1]`, etc. access those `option` elements.

The key quotes from the link above are:

> The `options` collection is also mirrored on the `HTMLSelectElement` object. The supported property indices at any instant are the indices supported by the object returned by the `options` attribute at that instant.

and

> The `length` IDL attribute must return the number of nodes represented by the `options` collection...

Comment: Any suggestion on how to convert it into an array where 1st and only element is the select?

Comment: @Whip - I'm afraid I don't understand the question.

Comment: nvm I figured it out `[].push(selectParent)`

Comment: @Whip - Or more directly, `[selectParent]`.